# Post Data using Express in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, fetch-api

I'm brand new to NodeJS. I'm trying to use the JavaScript fetch API on the client side to send data from a form the same way I would with PHP. I keep getting an error:
http://localhost:3000/submit net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

What am I doing wrong?

Here's the relevant part of my Index.html

```
  <form onsubmit="SubmitLogin(event);">
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" required><br>
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required><br>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
  
  <script>
    function SubmitLogin(Event) {
      Event.preventDefault();
      const formData = new FormData(Event.target);
      
      fetch('/submit', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data.message);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
    }
  </script>
```

Here's the relevant part of my App.js.

```
const app = express();
app.post('/submit', (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;

  console.log('Received data:', { username, password });

  // Create a new User document
  const newUser = new User({
    username,
    password,
  });

  // Save the new user to the existing MongoDB collection
  newUser.save((err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Error saving user:', err);
      res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error saving user' });
    } else {
      console.log('User saved successfully');
      res.status(200).json({ message: 'User saved successfully' });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Your express app is probably on a different port than your frontend app, right?  Use the full url in your fetch